# Contact Form ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, email, send, contacts

I have this in my View

Personal Details

Title

First name (s)

Last name

E-mail

Phone

Mobile

Message

submit

And can someone help me with controller function.I  have in this method up, for Contact Page and i dont know what to post in Controllor page. If some one can just show me how to do with first label or explain me what to do in cs page. 
Thanks

Comment: A complete tutorial is probably beyond the scope of Stack Overflow, but you can find a complete walkthrough here: http://content.wrox.com/wroxfiles/aspnetmvc-nerdinner_v2.pdf

Comment: Also here: http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: Its problem for me with labels and inputs, for example  i have list,<li>
                <label for="last_name">Last name</label>
                <input type="text" class="contact-form" name="last_name" id="last_name" />
                <div class="clear-fix"></div>
              </li> and in controller page i dont know what to do with id of this input.

Answer (score 6):

Have a model for contact with your values, like that:

ContactModel

```
string title { get; set; }
string firstName  { get; set; }
string lastName { get; set; }
string email { get; set; }
string phone { get; set; }
string mobile { get; set; }
string message { get; set; }
```

in your controller you can create a method (same name of your view)

ContactController

```
public ActionResult Contact(ContactModel newModel)
{
    //Do what you need to do
    return View();
}
```

in your view, do like that:

Contact

```
@model YourProjectName.Models.ContactModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Contact")) //send data to controller (Method name, Controller name)
{
    <fieldset>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.title)
        </div>

        // Do the same to all other values

        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: string Title = formCollection["title"];

This is how u get value from input, and that is what I needed.